# IndentGuide, possible to add color to selected scope?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, indentation

I'm using [IndentGuide](http://atlanto.github.io/IndentGuide/) to add Indent guidelines on in my eclipse, and it does really work well, there is just one thing can I would like to see, maybe its allready possible to do such thing.

If I'm having my mouse in a scope, is it then possible to change the active scope color, like on this image, here should indentguide show another color on the solid vertical line on line 9-13: [Indent Guide image](http://9l.dk/tmp/2013-08-06-17-52-27.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is impossible because IndentGuide is not parsing or analyzing with any languages. The scope or block or any language elements have no meanings to IndentGuide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciated! Do you know if its possible to remove some of the icons from [here](http://9l.dk/tmp/2013-08-07-08-28-14.png) (in the right corner) - Would be nice to have some of them removed